# Use of mysql lite and Web Service or other request througih an android app in different activities

Tags: android, web-services, sqlite, database-design, httpwebrequest

i am very new to the android development and i need to quickly develop a program. A requirement is to be able to call a web service and to store the information from the web-service in a database using sql-lite. Those request can be made in different activities.

also i would like to know in which activity or class to create the database,or how is it implemented in a simple app, relevant tutorials would be helpful.

Can I have a guideline on how to implement this, Whether using static method in an utility class or another strategy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have some apps that do stuff just like this, so yes, you can definitely achieve your objectives.

Here are some pointers:

- [HTTP Request](http://groups.google.com/group/android-beginners/browse_thread/thread/6db38705d3530769?pli=1)
- [SQLite Database](http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html)

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks, I am having a look at these. Could you please guide me on this: I need to request information from the web-service and to save the data in database in different activities. Do I need to implement those methods as static in a specific class?

Comment: having a class with static methods to do your web service lookups sounds like a reasonable approach. I myself have a Util class with functions of this type.